# Java assignment - unable to get matches regex to work correctly

Tags: java, regex

I'm supposed to be writing a code that reads a list of states and zip codes, find ones that have zip codes in the format of ###-### then print out to a .txt file. So far I have it reading/writing properly but when I try to put in the condition of matches.("\\d{3}-\\d{3}") it writes nothing as if the conditions aren't being satisfied. I've been searching online for hours but I have no idea whats wrong. As an example, the input file has each line written like this: "KS Kansas 660-699".

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("ziptable.txt");


    try{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(file);

        while(sc1.hasNextLine()){

            String oneLine = sc1.nextLine();
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(oneLine);
            String oneWord = sc2.nextLine();
            if(oneWord.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{3}")){
                System.out.println(oneWord);
            }
        }

        pw.close();
        sc1.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("File not found.");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) tells whether or not the entire string matches the given regular expression. If your input lines are in the format of "KS Kansas 660-699",  change your regular expression to the following.

```
if (oneWord.matches(".*\\d{3}-\\d{3}")) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work for your needs. I've included answers for an "agnostic" regex, as well as a Java-specific regex:

> Normal: `^\d{3}[-]\d{3}$`
>
> Java String Regex: `"^\\d{3}[-]\\d{3}$"`
>
> ^ = Start of the string.
>
> \d{3} = Match 3 digits
>
> [-] = Match a hyphen
>
> \d{3} = Match 3 digits
>
> $ = End of the string.